# How tall is Doomsday in Batman v. Superman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, doomsday

How tall is Doomsday in *Batman v. Superman* (2016)?

Sources would be appreciated.  If estimating please show your work.

Comment: The fan written wiki states ["At least 15 feet tall"](https://dccomicsextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Doomsday) but of course provides no reference.

Comment: I think I'll go change it to 30ft @TheLethalCarrot - just to illustrate the sometimes uselessness of wikia :D

Comment: He is precisely one plot high. That's 10 MiliRowlings

Answer (score 7):

An exact answer may be impossible but here is some math to suggest the closest possible estimation.

First lets compare by arm length

[image]

Henry Cavill is 6'1" via his [imdb page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0147147/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm). So given the length of his body in pixels to the length of doomsday's arm in [pixels](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/pixel-ruler.html) we have:

D = Doom:510px

S = Superman:342px

C = Cavill Ht in Inches: 73

S/C = 4.698 pixels per inch

D/(S/C) = 108.556 inches

Using arm to height formula [demi-span](http://www.rxkinetics.com/height_estimate.html) we have the following equation:

demispan = (D/(S/C))x2.54cm = 275.734cm

ESTIMATED HEIGHT = (1.40 x demispan(cm)) +57.8

ESTIMATED HEIGHT = (1.40 x 275.734cm) +57.8

ESTIMATED HEIGHT = 443.82cm

**ESTIMATED HEIGHT (feet & inches) = 14ft 6.74in**

Now lets compare the two closest side-by-side shots I could get:

[image]

D = Doom: 424px

S = Supes: 158px

C = Cavill Ht in Inches: 73

S/C = 2.164 pixels per inch

D/(S/C) = 195.933 inches

**ESTIMATED HEIGHT (feet & inches)= 16ft 3.9in**

[image]

Supes Diagonal height = √(length² + width²).

length = 31

width = 40

S = Supes Diagonal height = 50.6

D = Doom: 156px

C = Cavill Ht in Inches: 73

S/C = 1.442 inches per pixel

D(S/C) = 225 inches

**ESTIMATED HEIGHT (feet & inches)= 18ft 9in**

Now that is a big range. So lets do a final bit of maths.

Mean = (174.7 + 195.9 + 225)/3 = 198.53

Standard Deviation = 20.6

**Most likely height: 16ft 6.5in**

Also, the CGI guys probably didn't think it mattered that supes had a consistent size to doomsday, so we will have variation as they needed it (as evidenced by our measurements). If I where to go with just a single answer I would be likely to say the middle picture is the most correct at 16ft 3.9in given that this is the closest side by side we get. Also this is closest to the mean.

I also realize that comparision by pixel size of still images is imperfect. However, this is the closest we can get without knowing the exact dimensions that animators worked with per frame.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the work. These are all pre-nuke. In-story, size may change due to absorbing attacks. Could you confirm against the final size?  Est. time stamps: 2:38:45-2:38:50 (Ultimate Edition) & 2:39:13, might be possible to composite the two to get DD full body, and dead side-by-side w/ Supes should give a better measurement.

Comment: In that case Supes is 240 DD is 693 (not perfect on DD, that may be off by a bit as his head is cut off by the screen). That comes in at right about 17ft 7in. Bigger yes, may be due to my bad angle, bent legs and so on but its still is within 1 standard deviation.

Comment: However, if I had the full body, unbent, I think it would appear closer to 19-21ft range at death given Supes body is the length of DD's thigh.